# Diagonalization of total angular momentum over creation operators for an isotropic harmonic oscillator?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

You have an isotropic three dimensional quantum harmonic oscillator so the  Hamiltonian is
$$
H=\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{r^2}2
$$
If you do the creation-annihilation operator-algebra trick and define creation operator
$$
a^\dagger_j=\frac{x_j-ip_j}{\sqrt{2\hbar}}
$$
so that the Hamiltonian is
$$
H=\hbar  \left (a_1^\dagger a_1+a_2^\dagger a_2+a_3^\dagger a_3+\frac 3 2 \right)
$$
so that the Hamiltonian is diagonalized by states characterized by the excitation number in each direction.

BUT if we want to compute angular momentum, we could define $3$-rotating creation operators
$$
a_\uparrow^\dagger=\frac{a^\dagger_1+ia^\dagger_2}{\sqrt 2} \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ a_\downarrow^\dagger=\frac{a^\dagger_1-ia^\dagger_2}{\sqrt 2}
$$
and, as $a_1^\dagger a_1+a_2^\dagger a_2=a_\uparrow^\dagger a_\uparrow+a_\downarrow^\dagger a_\downarrow$, the Hamiltonian is still nicely diagonized; moreover  we also have the 3-angular momentum operator diagonal, $L_3=\hbar (a_\uparrow^\dagger a_\uparrow-a_\downarrow^\dagger a_\downarrow)$,  so $L_3 \left | n_\uparrow n_\downarrow n_z \right \rangle=\hbar (n_\uparrow-n_\downarrow) \left | n_\uparrow n_\downarrow n_z \right \rangle$.

How might you similarly diagonalize $L^2$ with respect to creation-annihilation? The spherical harmonics are hellish, but Schwinger's creation operator approach is so nice and intuitive. How could we compute $L^2$ probabilities without ever integrating again?

*Edit* More precisely: Are there commuting operators $a,b,c$ such that $[a,a^\dagger]=\hbar$ (etc for $b$ and $c$) and the set of states defined by 
$$\left | n_a n_b n_c \right \rangle=(a^\dagger)^{n_a}(b^\dagger)^{n_b}(c^\dagger)^{n_c}\left | \psi_0 \right \rangle$$
form an orthogonal basis diagonalizing $H,L^2$,and $L_3$? Here
 $\left | \psi_0 \right \rangle$ is the ground state. How can you determine $a,b,c$ algebraically?

Comment: Aren’t $H$ and $L^2$ essentially the same operator? (up to some scalar constants)

Comment: You probably want to read up in [Messiah QM vI](https://archive.org/details/QuantumMechanicsVolumeI/page/n239),   Ch XII,  § 15, p 456.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121503/angular-momentum-for-3d-harmonic-oscillator-in-two-different-bases#comment1010505_121503).

Comment: You are probably aware that the basis  $|n_\uparrow, n_\downarrow,n_3\rangle$ does *not* diagonalize $L^2$. You should emphasize that, to explain why you are wondering about the existence of yet another basis, a,b,c. It does not exist.